# How to find out if application is busy in VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, powerpoint

I'm trying to save a presentation as WMV file in VSTO 2012(C#) which takes a while and after saving it, close the powerpoint and display the media. But I can not determine when the saving is completed, and if I close the application before the saving is completed, everything will go wrong and there will be no file! The SaveAs method is apparently Async, so I was wondering if there is a way to realize the saving process is completed. something like application.isBusy?!

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation objPres = ppPresens.Open(strPresentationFile, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

objPres.SaveAs(filePath, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to check out [EApplication_PresentationSaveEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.eapplication_presentationsaveeventhandler%28v=office.14%29.aspx), which occurs before any open presentation is saved. Hopefully this would point you to the right direction.

You can register this event by using following code snippet:

```
Application.PresentationSave += new EApplication_PresentationSaveEventHandler(Application_PresentationSave);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can query ppMediaTaskStatus for this.

You can check its various values in the object browser of PPT's VBA IDE